# wpdb get_results no output while printing the column of a table

Tags: mysql, wordpress

Problem :

Using Wpdb trying to fetch a column from a table. The code i tried is :

```html
<?php
global $wpdb;
$sqlq2 = 'SELECT fk_id FROM `wp_productssku_mapping`';
$result = $wpdb->get_results($sqlq2);
foreach($result as $row)
 {
print_r($row->fk_id); 
 }
?>
```

This results in to blank page while hitting the

```
xyz.com/wp-content/themes/sometheme/name.php
```

In error log : Its blank ( No error related to this.)

What can be the probable problem?

**Update**

[image]

I have following data in the table, I need to fetch it one by one and use it in curl command.

Comment: Try to print_r($result); before foreach loop

Comment: @RaviKumar no change.

Comment: Try to print_r($result); exit; and see after press control U at bottom

Comment: If its not give any result then try to run query direct in database SELECT fk_id FROM `wp_productssku_mapping`

Answer (score 0):

after a quick read of [wpdb class reference](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#SELECT_Generic_Results), I got your above scenario to work with the following code snippet:

```
    global $wpdb;        
    $users = $wpdb->get_results( 'SELECT * FROM wp_users', ARRAY_A );

    foreach ($users as $user) {
        print_r($user);
    }
```

I believe the reason why it's not working for you is because you failed to specify an output type, reading the link above these are your options:

```
One of four pre-defined constants. Defaults to OBJECT. See SELECT a Row and its examples for more information.
OBJECT - result will be output as a numerically indexed array of row   objects.
OBJECT_K - result will be output as an associative array of row objects, using first column's values as keys (duplicates will be discarded).
ARRAY_A - result will be output as a numerically indexed array of associative arrays, using column names as keys.
ARRAY_N - result will be output as a numerically indexed array of numerically indexed arrays.
```

I personally prefer to work with associative arrays, but you want the object approach, then specify OBJECT as your second parameter in the get_results like so:

```
$users = $wpdb->get_results( 'SELECT * FROM wp_users', OBJECT );
```

and it should work out fine.

Complete solution below with OBJECT. Just swap out the variable names and table name.

```
    global $wpdb;        
    $users = $wpdb->get_results( 'SELECT * FROM wp_users', OBJECT );

    foreach ($users as $user) {
        print_r($user->ID);
    }
```

I've also just noticed that your trying to execute your php file directly, which is a big no no in wordpress. Your better off to create a function callback against a wordpress hook like admin_post. Chances are your never actually running code in the wordpress instance, and thusly $wpdb is most likely null.

take a read of the following: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_post_(action) on how to callback on the hook. You can use admin_post to create both post and get requests.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, if you can check the update in question, fetched column data is to be used in curl command one by one..

Comment: have you tried $result = $wpdb->get_results($sqlq2, OBJECT); and then using echo $row->fk_id?

Comment: Tried.. But No results.

Comment: before the for loop can you insert the following lines and paste back the output?

 $wpdb->show_errors();
$wpdb->print_error();

also a var_dump on your $results please.

Comment: No output changed after inserting two lines of code.